# How to select partition and sort keys for hierarchical model

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Please advise if this is not the right place to ask this.

I'm trying to find a suitable partition key/sort key pair for a simple relational model (a seller has many customers, a customer has many orders) that covers the following query patterns:

- For a given seller, get all orders for a given customer in a date range;
- For a given seller, get all orders for all customers in a date range.

My order ids are in the form `yyyy-mm-dd-random_string`, so it is sortable by date. There is only one item per order.

Using `seller_id` as partition key, and `customer_id#order_id` as sort key covers the first use case, but there is no way to "jump" over the customers.

How can I get these two queries from the same records?

Bonus:

- Is there a way to do it without secondary indexes?
- Is there a general approach for "jumping" over hierarchical relations?

Comment: Are you aware of the 'begins_with' function that you can use for key condition expressions?

Comment: @MatthewPope Yes. With the schema proposed in the question I can query `begins_with("customer_id#2019")` and it gets me all the orders for a customer for year 2019. But how can I get all orders placed in 2019 for all customers? Something like `/.*#2019.*/`.

Comment: It seems I misread your second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support your second query, you need to create a secondary index on `seller_id` and `order_id`.

There is a way to do it without secondary indexes, but it would require a full table scan.

The general approach to “jumping” over fields in a hierarchical key schema is to create a GSI with a key that omits the field that you are “jumping”.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was an idiom or a pattern for queries like this without having to create a second index. Oh well...